# Shape of Tensorflow Weights

Tags: tensorflow

I have X_train with shape(1599,11) and y_train with shape (1599,). But I cannot decide the shape of the weight matrix. I am new to tensorflow.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32)

w = tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 0.1, shape = []))
b = tf.Variable(initial_value = 0.1)

y_hat = tf.matmul(X,w) + b
```

Comment: The shape of the weight matrix should be the shape of your input matrix

Comment: Here X _train is my input matrix but setting shape = (1599,11) gives me invalid argument error

Comment: Set X_train shape in X placeholder as X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(1599,11)) and w as tf.Variable(initial_value = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 0.1, shape = [11, 1]))

Comment: How did you determine shape = [11,1] because my X has 11 columns and y is just 1 column?